# Fed Ex Shipping india error message in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping, fedex

Fed Ex Shipping india 'Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time' in production mode magento 2.1

I am using Magento 2.1.3 integrated fed ex shipping module with built-in module for India based store for domestic shipping. `Debug-log` response is request successfully processed but `Exception-log` is giving a critical Exception:

> main.CRITICAL: exception 'Exception' with message 'Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ShipmentRateDetail in /public_html/vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model/Carrier.php on line 671' in/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
>   Stack trace:

```
#0 public_html/vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model/Carrier.php(671): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined prope...', '/home/atlan621/...', 671, Array)
#1 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model/Carrier.php(615): Magento\Fedex\Model\Carrier->_getRateAmountOriginBased(Object(stdClass))
#2 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model/Carrier.php(576): Magento\Fedex\Model\Carrier->_prepareRateResponse(Object(stdClass))
#3 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model/Carrier.php(288): Magento\Fedex\Model\Carrier->_getQuotes()
#4 public_html/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php(293): Magento\Fedex\Model\Carrier->collectRates(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#5 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php(209): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping->collectCarrierRates('fedex', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#6 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address.php(995): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping->collectRates(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#7 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address.php(936): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address->requestShippingRates()
#8 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Shipping.php(161): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address->collectShippingRates()
#9 public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/TotalsCollector.php(265): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Shipping->collect(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAssignment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total))
#10 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingMethodManagement.php(273): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector->collectAddressTotals(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))
#11 /home/atlan621/public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingMethodManagement.php(213): Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement->getShippingMethods(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote), Array)
#12 [internal function]: Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement->estimateByExtendedAddress('1437', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))
#13 /home/atlan621/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(307): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(216): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()
#15 public_html/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 //public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#18 /public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#19 {main}

Next exception 'Exception' with message 'Report ID: webapi-596c83febd24a; Message: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ShipmentRateDetail in public_html/vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model/Carrier.php on line 671' in public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:195
Stack trace:
#0 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php(139): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(Exception))
/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(219): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(Exception))
#2 public_html/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#5 /public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
"Undefined property: stdClass::$ShipmentRateDetai"
```

this error occurs when we try to get the value of index but that particular index does not exist...

and also in magento 2.1.3 in line no 671 there is no such code is specified  for getting value of that index..so  it looks like you have customized the code.

Comment: exception-log error is not raising just selecting the different allow methods. Still Shipping charges are not displaying on front-end.